# merge two datasets using partial string match in R

Tags: r

I have two data sets as follows `df1` and `df2`. I want to merge both into one `df` by matching `df1$pkg` and `df2$name`. But the strings in `df1$pkg` and `df2$name` are not exactly same. I tried using `agrep` but that did not work. Will appreciate any help.

```
x<-agrep(df1[,2], df2[,1],ignore.case=T, value=T)
Warning message:
In agrep(df1[, 2], df2[, 1], ignore.case = T, value = T) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> x
character(0)



df1<<-data.frame(apname=c("photo eff pro", "olx", "firefox", "word search", "chrome","bbc news"), 
             pkg=c("bbc.mobile.news", "com.dhqsolutions", "#com.olx.olx","org.mozilla.firefox","ws.letras", "com.chrome"),
             apcat=c(5,3,4,5,4,1))
df2<-data.frame(name=c("bbc.mob.news.ww", "com.dhqsolutions.enjoyphoto", "com.olx.olx","org.mozilla.firefox","ws.letras","chrome.approximated"),
            tic=c(10000, 12345, 123456, 23456,9903, 12389034))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use one of the `apply` family of functions ([see this excellent Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)) or some type of loop.  That's why you receive the warning message.  Consider this simple example:

```
vec1 <- c("Dog", "Cat", "Pony")
vec2 <- c("catty", "doggy", "fish", "ponyt")
sapply(vec1, agrep, vec2)
# Dog  Cat  Pony 
#   2    1     4
```

In your case, you will likely want to do something like: `sapply(df1$pkg, agrep, df2$name)`

Comment: I need all the attributes apname, pkg,apcat, name, tic in one data frame. How do I do that ?